# .htaccess file forces php download, how do I change it to run instead?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file, what do I need to change to make it run php files instead of downloading it?

```
##Custom 404 page##
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
####

##remove .html##
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
####

#Force non-www:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
####

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
####

## GZIP ##
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
</IfModule>
####

## GZIP Alternative ##
 <ifModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
####

## ENABLE CORS ##
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css|js|gif|png|jpe?g|svg|svgz|ico|webp)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
####

## specify character coding ##
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
####

## KeepAlive ##
<ifModule mod_headers.c> 
    Header set Connection keep-alive 
</ifModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

This .htaccess file was created by previous developer and I do not want to break existing website.
At the moment any url that ends with .php will be downloaded instead of executed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"...any url that ends with .php will be downloaded instead of executed"* ... That may not have anything to do with the `.htaccess` file - that *sounds* more like the PHP engine isn't enabled on the server.

Comment: Sounds like PHP isn't installed. Are you accessing the files through a web server or are you opening the files directly in the browser?

Comment: `AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml` <- that implies that your server is running cPanel on EasyApache? (configured to use PHP 5.6 - oooh, creaky). You *should* be able to manage this through cPanel itself - assuming you've got a login.

Comment: @CD001 I have a subdomain on same domain with a php application running without any issues. My CPanel has same php version settings for both domain and subdomain. Does that answer your point, or do I need to check something else to confirm?

Comment: @CD001 PHP 7.3 (ea-php73) with cpanel login. Like I said a previous developer created the .htaccess file and uploaded it without knowing the server environment.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am accessing the files through browser. The same account has a subdomain with same settings in cpanel and is running a php application on the subdomain.

Comment: That's weird as that's not being reflected in the `.htaccess` file... unfortunately I've not really used cPanel for a very long time - but, from a quick Googling about, it looks like something to do with the [MultiPHP setting](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/84Docs/MultiPHP+Manager+for+cPanel). Not sure I'm going to be much help here - sorry :|

Comment: The original developer solved the issue, but did not give a reason why this happened. I will need to investigate what changed to answer the question.